# Update dataframe from another dataframe, but only where values have changed

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Based on previous answers, I am not able to find a solution to my problem. I have got someway there, but I'm just a bit stuck now..

I have two dataframes:

```
df_master = pd.DataFrame({'Reference_Code':['19860', '20220'],
        'Price_Now':[249.99, 149.99],
        'Price_Was':['',159.99],
        'In_Stock':['',''],
        'Updated':['',''],        
            })

df_master
Reference_Code  Price_Now   Price_Was   In Stock    Updated
19860           249.99      
20220           149.99      159.99

df_output = pd.DataFrame({'Reference_Code':['19860', '20220', '52458','12546'], 
                          'Price_Now':[249.99, 149.99, 12.99, 19.99], 
                          'Price_Was':['',159.99,'',''], 
                          'Updated':['30/10/2021','','',''],
                         }) 


df_output
Reference_Code  Price_Now   Price_Was   Updated
19860           259.99                  30/10/2021
20220           149.99      159.99
52458           12.99
12546           19.99
```

I want the result in df_master to be as below (I will be appending new records separately):

```
df_master
Reference_Code  Price_Now   Price_Was   Updated
19860           259.99                  30/10/2021
20220           149.99      159.99
```

The steps I think I need to achieve this:

Step 1
Create a new dataframe called df_match showing the rows in df_master which match df_output based on ['Reference_Code'] using the following code

```
code1= list(df_master['Reference_Code'])
df_match = df_output.loc[df_output['Reference_Code'].isin(code1)]
```

Step2
Remove the rows from `df_match` where the `df_match['Price_Now']` is equal to `df_output['Price_Now']`. This will leave the dataframe with only those values which have an updated/different value in `df_output['Price_Now']`.

Step 3
Use the remaining items in `df_match` as a the items to update in `df_master`, update the values in `df_master['Price_Now']` using the value from `df_output['Price_Now']`

Step 4
At the same time, use the remaining items in `df_match` to update the `df_master['Updated']` with a variable '`todaysdate`'

Any advice on my approach, and how to achieve this would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is the following:

```
df_master_redux = df_master.drop(['In_Stock'], axis = 1)
df_ouput = pd.concat([df_master_redux, df_output]).reset_index()
df_ouput = df_ouput.drop_duplicates()
df_ouput = df_ouput.sort_values(['Reference_Code']).groupby('Reference_Code').tail(1).drop(['index'], axis=1)
```

which returns:

```
Reference_Code  Price_Now Price_Was     Updated
5          12546      19.99                      
2          19860     249.99            30/10/2021
1          20220     149.99    159.99            
4          52458      12.99
```